# How to show a webgrid in a modal when a link is clicked

Tags: jquery, webmatrix, webgrid

I have been taking advantage of mikedotnetting tutorials and samples. From this  [link](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/176/WebMatrix-and-jQuery-Forms-Part-2-Editing-Data) I  am building a CRUD application. First a user searches or filters the webgrid. The results shown have two buttons which are links to a modal window or dialog. Below is part of the code for the webgrid:

```
 grid.Column("", format: @<button class="edit-recipient" id="@item.ID">Edit</button>),
  ....
 grid.Column("", format: @<button class="view-recipient" id="@item.ID">View</button>)
```

Once a user clicks the Edit button, a pop up window comes and from the jquery values are populated by use of getJSON.

My intention is to have the View button show a pop up window with values in a webgrid as this   is a one to many relationship with ID the foreign key in the modal window in question. 
I couldnt use the object from getJSON to bind the webgrid successful likely because the webgrid requires a model. I have to pass the ID value to method which queries the database and binds to a webgrid.

The additions I made from [link](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/176/WebMatrix-and-jQuery-Forms-Part-2-Editing-Data) are the View button which has to show webgrid and the search functionality only.

I could post the whole code but the link I provide has most of the code.

Comment: Is this along the lines of what you want? http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: More than that. I already have modal window with edit functionality and getJSON data binding to it. My intention is for the view button to show a modal window with webgrid in it. How to pass show the webgrid in it is the hard part.